# Xna (MonoGame) DynamicSoundEffectInstance Buffer already Full exception

Tags: xna, monogame, soundbuffer

I'm making this game in MonoGame (basically Xna) that uses DynamicSoundEffectInstance class. MonoGame does not have an implementation of DynamicSoundEffectInstance yet, so I made my own:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
#if MONOMAC
using MonoMac.OpenAL;
#else
using OpenTK.Audio.OpenAL;
#endif
using System.Threading;

namespace Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio
{
public sealed class DynamicSoundEffectInstance : IDisposable
{
    private const int BUFFERCOUNT = 2;

    private SoundState soundState = SoundState.Stopped;
    private AudioChannels channels;
    private int sampleRate;
    private ALFormat format;
    private bool looped = false;
    private float volume = 1.0f;
    private float pan = 0;
    private float pitch = 0f;
    private int sourceId;
    private int[] bufferIds;
    private int[] bufferIdsToFill;
    private int currentBufferToFill;
    private bool isDisposed = false;
    private bool hasSourceId = false;
    private Thread bufferFillerThread = null;

    // Events
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> BufferNeeded;

    internal void OnBufferNeeded(EventArgs args)
    {
        if (BufferNeeded != null)
        {
            BufferNeeded(this, args);
        }
    }

    public DynamicSoundEffectInstance(int sampleRate, AudioChannels channels)
    {
        this.sampleRate = sampleRate;
        this.channels = channels;
        switch (channels)
        {
        case AudioChannels.Mono:
            this.format = ALFormat.Mono16;
            break;
        case AudioChannels.Stereo:
            this.format = ALFormat.Stereo16;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }                       
    }

    public bool IsDisposed
    {
        get
        {
            return isDisposed;
        }
    }

    public float Pan
    {
        get
        {
            return pan;
        }

        set
        {
            pan = value;
            if (hasSourceId)
            {
                // Listener
                // Pan
                AL.Source(sourceId, ALSource3f.Position, pan, 0.0f, 0.1f);
            }
        }
    }

    public float Pitch
    {
        get
        {
            return pitch;
        }
        set
        {
            pitch = value;
            if (hasSourceId)
            {
                // Pitch
                AL.Source(sourceId, ALSourcef.Pitch, XnaPitchToAlPitch(pitch));
            }
        }
    }

    public float Volume
    {
        get
        {
            return volume;
        }

        set
        {
            volume = value;
            if (hasSourceId)
            {
                // Volume
                AL.Source(sourceId, ALSourcef.Gain, volume * SoundEffect.MasterVolume);
            }

        }
    }   

    public SoundState State
    {
        get
        {
            return soundState;
        }
    }

    private float XnaPitchToAlPitch(float pitch)
    {
        // pitch is different in XNA and OpenAL. XNA has a pitch between -1 and 1 for one octave down/up.
        // openAL uses 0.5 to 2 for one octave down/up, while 1 is the default. The default value of 0 would make it completely silent.
        return (float)Math.Exp(0.69314718 * pitch);
    }

    public void Play()
    {
        if (!hasSourceId)
        {
            bufferIds = AL.GenBuffers(BUFFERCOUNT);
            sourceId = AL.GenSource();
            hasSourceId = true;
        }
        soundState = SoundState.Playing;

        if (bufferFillerThread == null)
        {
            bufferIdsToFill = bufferIds;
            currentBufferToFill = 0;
            OnBufferNeeded(EventArgs.Empty);
            bufferFillerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(BufferFiller));
            bufferFillerThread.Start();
        }

        AL.SourcePlay(sourceId);
    }

    public void Apply3D(AudioListener listener, AudioEmitter emitter)
    {
        Apply3D(new AudioListener[] { listener }, emitter);
    }

    public void Pause()
    {
        if (hasSourceId)
        {
            AL.SourcePause(sourceId);
            soundState = SoundState.Paused;
        }
    }


    public void Apply3D(AudioListener[] listeners, AudioEmitter emitter)
    {
        // get AL's listener position
        float x, y, z;
        AL.GetListener(ALListener3f.Position, out x, out y, out z);

        for (int i = 0; i < listeners.Length; i++)
        {
            AudioListener listener = listeners[i];

            // get the emitter offset from origin
            Vector3 posOffset = emitter.Position - listener.Position;
            // set up orientation matrix
            Matrix orientation = Matrix.CreateWorld(Vector3.Zero, listener.Forward, listener.Up);
            // set up our final position and velocity according to orientation of listener
            Vector3 finalPos = new Vector3(x + posOffset.X, y + posOffset.Y, z + posOffset.Z);
            finalPos = Vector3.Transform(finalPos, orientation);
            Vector3 finalVel = emitter.Velocity;
            finalVel = Vector3.Transform(finalVel, orientation);

            // set the position based on relative positon
            AL.Source(sourceId, ALSource3f.Position, finalPos.X, finalPos.Y, finalPos.Z);
            AL.Source(sourceId, ALSource3f.Velocity, finalVel.X, finalVel.Y, finalVel.Z);
        }
    }


    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (!isDisposed)
        {
            Stop(true);
            AL.DeleteBuffers(bufferIds);
            AL.DeleteSource(sourceId);
            bufferIdsToFill = null;
            hasSourceId = false;
            isDisposed = true;
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        if (hasSourceId)
        {
            AL.SourceStop(sourceId);
            int pendingBuffers = PendingBufferCount;
            if(pendingBuffers > 0)
                AL.SourceUnqueueBuffers(sourceId, PendingBufferCount);
            if (bufferFillerThread != null)
                bufferFillerThread.Abort();
            bufferFillerThread = null;
        }
        soundState = SoundState.Stopped;
    }

    public void Stop(bool immediate)
    {
        Stop();
    }

    public TimeSpan GetSampleDuration(int sizeInBytes)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int GetSampleSizeInBytes(TimeSpan duration)
    {
        int size = (int)(duration.TotalMilliseconds * ((float)sampleRate / 1000.0f));
        return (size + (size & 1)) * 16;
    }

    public void SubmitBuffer(byte[] buffer)
    {
        this.SubmitBuffer(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }

    public void SubmitBuffer(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        if (bufferIdsToFill != null) {
            AL.BufferData (bufferIdsToFill [currentBufferToFill], format, buffer, count, sampleRate);
            AL.SourceQueueBuffer (sourceId, bufferIdsToFill [currentBufferToFill]);
            currentBufferToFill++;
            if (currentBufferToFill >= bufferIdsToFill.Length)
                bufferIdsToFill = null;
            else
                OnBufferNeeded (EventArgs.Empty);
        } else {
            throw new  Exception ("Buffer already full.");
        }
    }

    private void BufferFiller()
    {
        bool done = false;

        while (!done)
        {
            var state = AL.GetSourceState(sourceId);
            if (state == ALSourceState.Stopped || state == ALSourceState.Initial)
                AL.SourcePlay(sourceId);

            if (bufferIdsToFill != null)
                continue;

            int buffersProcessed;
            AL.GetSource(sourceId, ALGetSourcei.BuffersProcessed, out buffersProcessed);

            if (buffersProcessed == 0)
                continue;

            bufferIdsToFill = AL.SourceUnqueueBuffers(sourceId, buffersProcessed);
            currentBufferToFill = 0;
            OnBufferNeeded(EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    public bool IsLooped
    {
        get
        {
            return looped;
        }

        set
        {
            looped = value;                
        }
    }

    public int PendingBufferCount 
    {
        get
        {
            if (hasSourceId)
            {
                int buffersQueued;
                AL.GetSource(sourceId, ALGetSourcei.BuffersQueued, out buffersQueued);
                return buffersQueued;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
}   
}
```

Now, I followed [this](http://www.david-gouveia.com/creating-a-basic-synth-in-xna-part-ii/) tutorial on making dynamic sounds in Xna, which worked with my custom MonoGame class. However, when I run the project (Xamarin Studio 4, Mac OS X 10.8, with MonoGame 3.0.1), it throws this exception:

```
Buffer already full
```

Pointing at the code in my custom class:

```
    public void SubmitBuffer(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        if (bufferIdsToFill != null) {
            AL.BufferData (bufferIdsToFill [currentBufferToFill], format, buffer, count, sampleRate);
            AL.SourceQueueBuffer (sourceId, bufferIdsToFill [currentBufferToFill]);
            currentBufferToFill++;
            if (currentBufferToFill >= bufferIdsToFill.Length)
                bufferIdsToFill = null;
            else
                OnBufferNeeded (EventArgs.Empty);
        } else {
            throw new  Exception ("Buffer already full."); //RIGHT HERE IS THE EXCEPTION
        }
    }
```

I commented out the exception, and ran it again. It played the sound, with pops in it, but it still played it. How can I clear the buffer, so it is not full? I followed [this](http://www.david-gouveia.com/creating-a-basic-synth-in-xna-part-ii/) tutorial EXACTLY, so all the code I added to my project is in there.

Comment: Have you posted this question on the MonoGame forums? I'm sure they would be interested in putting your implementation in the official code once the bugs are fixed.

Comment: @craftworkgames Not yet. This code seams to work with every platform except Android. It's because Android does not support OpenAL, which is what they use. I'm trying to implement OpenSL ES, which is supported by Android.

Comment: They want to support Android so if they have to use OpenSL ES they probably will.

Comment: @craftworkgames Exactly. However, I can't find any C# wrappers for OpenSL ES. I don't feel like writing one myself, I'm sure SOMEBODY has written one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh! Figured it out myself; I changed the pending buffer count from 3 to 2. My final submit buffer code was:

```
while(_instance.PendingBufferCount < 2)
            SubmitBuffer();
```

Where the 2 is, used to be a 3. Now it no longer throws the exception.

Comment: Maybe I'm misinterpreting the purpose here, but wouldn't it read better if it said if(_instance.PendingBufferCount == 1)

Comment: @craftworkgames yes, I suppose that would probably be better. But, at the moment, I had wanted to try to follow the tutorial as best that I could, so I kept the less than code, with just changing the 3 to a 2.